# Cython installation (python -m pip install kivy)

Tags: installation, cython

How to solve these error :

> c:\users\home pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ficc_3vk\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Have you looked for  file: 'GL/glew.h'? The error is quite clear.

Comment: pip-build-ficc_3vk folder doesnot exist in the temp folder.